# Excluding hidden files from du command output with --exclude, grep -v or sed

Tags: bash, sed, grep, hidden, du

I'm trying to check with Disk Usage tool how big are my home directory folders but it also prints out folders and files starting with dot.

I can't seem to filter them out.

```
du -h --exclude="?"
du -h | grep -v "?"
du -h | grep -ve "?"
du -h | sed "?"
```

Thanks in advance.

edit>
Thank you **SiegeX** for you answer.

```
du -h --max-depth=1 | grep -v "./\\."
```

Since dot matches any character we have to prefix it with double backslash since its also a special character.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If running `du` with no specified path (current dir), use this:

```
du -h --exclude "./.*"
```

Comment: Try `du -sh --exclude "./.*"` if you only want the total

Answer (score 0):

From `du` manual (Use `man du` to see the manual):

```
-I mask files and directories matching the specified mask.
```

In your case this command should work when executed in in desired path.

```bash
du -h -I [^.]*
```