# Exclude all permission denied messages from "du"

Tags: linux, shell, warnings, suppress-warnings, du

I am trying to evaluate the disk usage of a number of Unix user accounts.
Simply, I am using the following command:

```
du -cBM --max-depth=1 | sort -n
```

But I’ve seen many error message like below. How can I exclude all such “Permission denied” messages from display?

```
du: `./james/.gnome2': Permission denied
```

**My request could be very similar to the following list, by replacing “find” to “du”.**

[How can I exclude all "permission denied" messages from "find"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762348)

The following thread does not work. I guess I am using bash.

[Excluding hidden files from du command output with --exclude, grep -v or sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5463884)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

```
du -cBM --max-depth=1 2>/dev/null | sort -n
```

or better in bash (just filter out this particular error, not all like last snippet)

```
du -cBM --max-depth=1 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied') | sort -n
```

Comment: @MevatlaveKraspek - thank you! if you have time, could you explain what "2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied')" does?

Comment: `-v` is an inverse match. So seems like it just filters `stderr` (2>) and only hides `Permission denied` errors instead of hiding all errors like in the first command.

Comment: can stack the greps like
du -cBM --max-depth=1 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied') | grep -v 'cannot access' | sort -n, it is also possible to add multiple terms to grep with an OR

Comment: if one day stackoverflow will go down, we all go back to the stone age

Comment: Taking this nice answer, I made a small modification, to make it more human-readable: du -h -cBM --max-depth=1 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied') | sort -n

Answer (score 11):

To remove all errors coming from the du command i used this:

```
du -sh 2>&1 | grep -v  '^du:'
```

Answer (score 9):

2> /dev/null hides only error messages.

the command du always try run over directory. Imagine that you have thousands of directories?

du needs eval, if you have persmission run if not, follow with the next dir...

Answer (score 9):

I'd use something concise that excludes only the lines you don't want to see. Redirect stderr to stdout, and grep to exclude all "denied"s:

```
du -cBM --max-depth=1 2>&1 | grep -v 'denied' | sort -n
```

Answer (score 2):

If `2>/dev/null` does not work, probably the shell you are using is not `bash`.

To check what shell you are using, you may try `ps -p $$` (see https://askubuntu.com/a/590903/130162 )

Answer (score 2):

you can pipe it to a temporary file, like -

du ...  **> temp_file**

Errors get printed on the terminal and only disk usage information gets printed into the temp_file.

Comment: Great, but you need to have disk space for the temp file, which is not a given.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
sudo du / 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied') 2> >(grep -v 'cannot access') | sort -n
```

Alternative I like more and use, just showing top directories and human binary prefixes (although not a real ordering):

```
sudo du -h -d 1 / 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied') 2> >(grep -v 'cannot access') | sort -n
```

Output example:

```
0   /dev
0   /proc
0   /sys
2.2G    /opt
2.6M    /run
4.0K    /cdrom
4.0K    /srv
7.4G    /snap
8.7G    /usr
12K /media
16K /lost+found
19M /etc
24G /var
48K /mnt
67M /volumes
86M /root
240K    /tmp
295G    /home
305M    /boot
338G    /
```

Instead, if you want a real ordering (but less human-readable), try:

```
sudo du -d 1 / 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied') 2> >(grep -v 'cannot access') | sort -n
```

Output example:

```
0   /dev
0   /proc
0   /sys
4   /cdrom
4   /srv
12  /media
16  /lost+found
48  /mnt
240 /tmp
2632    /run
19216   /etc
68260   /volumes
87512   /root
311420  /boot
2237740 /opt
7755733 /snap
9018580 /usr
25068772    /var
308849688   /home
353419881   /
```